# why $(\sum 8(n-1)) +1$ is equals to $(2n-1)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

(Forgive me if it is a silly question)
When I was solving a puzzle, I observed a sequence

```
1, 1+8, 1+8+16, 1+8+16+24, 1+8+16+24+32....
```

is equals to

```
1,   9,     25,     49,    81.....
```

for which I see it as:

$(8 \times 0) +1, (8 \times 0 + 8 \times 1) +1, (8 \times 0 + 8 \times 1 + 8 \times 2) +1, (8 \times 1 + 8 \times 2 + 8 \times 3 + 8 \times 4) +1 ....$
equals to

$1^2, 3^2, 5^2, 7^2 ...$

and my brain stuck here and cannot find out the relationship between two series.

Can someone give me a hint why $(\sum 8(n-1)) +1$ is equals to $(2n-1)^2$

Comment: $(2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5)=60$ seems to make a problem

Comment: 1+8+16+32=57 not 49.

Comment: n^2 =1+3+5+...+2n-1=1+8+16 +24+32+...8*(n-1).

Comment: oops I I think I make some mistakes here. lemme fix it

Comment: I think it just looks like a pattern and basically you are doing the equivalent of expressing squares in binary Wichita seem to have a paternity early on.  The odd squares in binary are 1,1001, 110001,1010001, 1111001. Which looks like pattern but probably isnt.

Comment: "why" is a funny word in the world of math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the terms grow linearly, their average is also the average of the extreme values. Hence the sum for the $n$ first terms
$$S_n=n\cdot\frac{0+8(n-1)}2+1=4n^2-4n+1=(2n-1)^2.$$

Comment: I love this explanation! Easy to understand for people without much math background like me :D  !

Answer (score 1):

Hint summation of$n$  odd integers which are positive is $n^2$ which can be expresed as $\sum (2n-1)=n^2$ where $n\in N$

Answer (score 1):

$$S_1=1=(2\cdot1-1)^2,\\
S_n-S_{n-1}=(2n-1)^2-(2n-3)^2=8n-8.$$

---

You can establish the formula using the well-known triangular numbers,

$$1+2+3+\cdots n=\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$

Then

$$S_n=8\frac{(n-1)n}2+1=4n^2-4n+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$(n+1)^2 = n^2+(2n+1) $ so by induction $n^2= \sum 2k-1$

And for just the odd squares. $(2n+1)^2= 1 + \sum_{k=2;+2}^{2n} [(2k - 1)+(2k+1) ]= 1 +4\sum_{j=1}^{n }2j=1+8\sum j$